# How to start a Spring project obtained from a Swagger file

Tags: spring, swagger

Hello I am trying to develop an application which starts on Spring from a swagger file (.json file). I am trying to find a plugin for converting from swagger file to spring server classes. I have not found any helpful solution.
I also do not have idea on how to make and start the Spring when the application starts.
Any idea ???
Thanks
Gorka

Comment: It seems you want to generate a Spring-based client from the given swagger.json file. Here you can generate clients: http://editor.swagger.io (I'm sure you know this link already, but still). And then you can implement your own generator using a source code from the offical Swagger Editor repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've a Swagger/OpenAPI spec, you can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate Spring MVC or Boot server stub.

Here are some examples:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO#java-spring-mvc

If you've any feedback on Swagger Codegen, please open a [ticket](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new)